# How to save the value of textarea to localstorage then display it in the same textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm creating a simple note storing application and would like the values of all text areas to be saved to the local storage when the user hits a save button. When the user returns I would like the textareas to display the saved notes. Below I will add the relevent code. As for now, when I reload the page the textareas aren't filled with the notes and I can't figure out why.

JSLint errors: https://gyazo.com/c2271b41e83a7d3f81ee024386832e5b

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
     <button id="note1btn" data-role="button">Note #1</button>
     <textarea id="note1input" class="textarea hide" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

     <button id="note2btn" data-role="button">Note #2</button>
     <textarea id="note2input" class="textarea hide" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

     <button id="note3btn" data-role="button">Note #3</button>
     <textarea id="note3input" class="textarea hide" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

     <button id="note4btn" data-role="button">Note #4</button>
     <textarea id="note4input" class="textarea hide" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

     <button id="note5btn" data-role="button">Note #5</button>
     <textarea id="note5input" class="textarea hide" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

     <button id="note6btn" data-role="button">Note #6</button>
     <textarea id="note6input" class="textarea hide" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

     <button id="note7btn" data-role="button">Note #7</button>
     <textarea id="note7input" class="textarea hide" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

     <button id="note8btn" data-role="button">Note #8</button>
     <textarea id="note8input" class="textarea hide" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

     <button id="note9btn" data-role="button">Note #9</button>
     <textarea id="note9input" class="textarea hide" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

      <button id="note10btn" data-role="button">Note #10</button>
      <textarea id="note10input" class="textarea hide" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

      <button id="savenotesbtn" data-role="button">Save</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var savesnotesbtn = document.getElementById("savenotesbtn");

    //FILL TEXT AREAS WITH NOTES
    for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        $("#note" + i + "input").val(localStorage.getItem("note" + i));
    }


    //SWIPE LEFT
    $(document).on('swipeleft', '.ui-page', function (event) {
        if (event.handled !== true) { // This will prevent event triggering more then once   
            var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role="page"]');
            // swipe using id of next page if exists
            if (nextpage.length > 0) {
                $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
            }
            event.handled = true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    //SWIFE RIGHT
    $(document).on('swiperight', '.ui-page', function (event) {
        if (event.handled !== true) { // This will prevent event triggering more then once
            var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
            if (prevpage.length > 0) {
                $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
            }
            event.handled = true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    //DISPLAY NOTE
    $("body").on('click', '[id^="note"]', function (e) {
        $(this).next('textarea').toggleClass("hide");
    });

    $(".textarea").on('input', function () {
        $("#savenotesbtn").addClass("notSaved");
    });


    savesnotesbtn.addEventListener("click", saveNotes);

});

//SAVE NOTES
    function saveNotes() {
        //Change styles of button
        $("#savenotesbtn").removeClass("notSaved").addClass("Saved");       

        //Save notes in local storage
        for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        localStorage.getItem("note" + i, $("#note" + i + "input").val());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get values by [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `value` (`value` is property from vanilla javascript, not jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var savesnotesbtn = document.getElementById("savenotesbtn");

    //FILL TEXT AREAS WITH NOTES
    for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
      $("#note" + i + "input").val(localStorage.getItem("note" + i));
    }

    function saveNotes() {
      //Change styles of button
      $("#savenotesbtn").removeClass("notSaved").addClass("Saved");
      // Save data to localstorage
      for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        localStorage.setItem("note" + i, $("#note" + i + "input").val());
      }
    };
    savesnotesbtn.addEventListener("click", saveNotes);
});
```

Comment: An explanation would've been way better, because the author is obviously just starting to learn JavaScript and jQuery. This is too advanced. You should either explain what you're doing or just update the authors initial code, otherwise he will just copy without understanding.

Comment: This makes sense to me, I just haven't used a lot of jQuery so I was unaware of .val() instead of .value

Comment: @NikxDa, I've added some

Comment: @br3t Thank you, I've added this code but it's still not working for me. The textboxes now contain 'undefined' so it seems to be getting the locastorage value correctly but if I alter them, save it and reload the page the values remain as undefined

Comment: @br3t I will update the question with my entire code if you wouldn't mind checking it to see if you know what the problem is

Comment: In this case, at least do it completely right: http://codepen.io/NikxDa/pen/vxjgpb

Comment: @EthanBristow , to save values use `localStorage.setItem`

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Didn't see that. Thank you very much for your help @br3t

Comment: @EthanBristow, that's ok, it was my copy-paste mistake too in one of drafts of my answer

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `.value` on a jQuery object. Use jQuery's `.val()` function to set and get the value instead.
For example:

```
$("#note1input").val(localStorage.getItem ("abc")); //Get
localStorage.setItem ($("#note1input").val()); //Set
```

Full working example with auto-save would be this:
HTML:

```
<input data-store="1"></input>
<input data-store="2"></input>
<input data-store="3"></input>
<input data-store="4"></input>
<input data-store="5"></input>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
  $("*[data-store]").each(function () {
    $(this).val(localStorage.getItem("item-" + $(this).attr("data-store")));
  });

  $("*[data-store]").on("keyup", function (itm) {
    localStorage.setItem ("item-" + $(this).attr("data-store"), $(this).val());
  })
})
```

Check out: http://codepen.io/NikxDa/pen/vxjgpb

Comment: Thanks @NikxDa but I'm confiused about how you used 'abc' for the getItem. How does it know what to fill the textarea with as it's not saved as a particular name

Comment: Would I put localStorage.setItem("note1", $("#note1input").val()); ?

Comment: You don't, this is just an example of the usage. Just replace every `.value` with `.val()`. Therefore `noteX = $("#noteXitem").value` becomes `noteX = $("#noteXitem").val()` and `$("#noteXItem").value = localStorage.getItem ("noteX")` becomes `$("#noteXItem").val(localStorage.getItem("noteX"))`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @NikxDa